# Is there a way to find what AD groups are listed on a folder's permissions list in powershell?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I see a lot of posts of people trying to find what folders a group has access to, but I am trying to do the opposite. I want to find the groups that are linked to a folder.

Here is my code:

```
$FolderPath = "W:\my_path"

$GroupPrefix = "A_Known_Prefix_Of_Each_Group"

$Acl = Get-Acl -Path $FolderPath
$Groups = $Acl.Access |
   Where-Object { $_.IdentityReference.Value -like "${GroupPrefix}*" } |
   Select-Object -ExpandProperty IdentityReference

Write-Host "AD groups with access to $FolderPath->"
$Groups
```

But it can't seem to list AD groups. It can list local groups though. Here is the result without doing any filtering

```
Permission groups with access to W:\my_folder->

Value
-----
CREATOR OWNER
NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM
BUILTIN\Administrators
S-1-5-21-2116170847-193796598-433219294-82478
```

But when I look for the one I want with the prefix filter my output is:

```
AD groups with access to W:\my_folder->
```

Finally, here is a screenshot of the permissions on the folder where the red is the prefix:

[image: Image of folder permissions]

I am doing this so I can automate adding users to a group when they request access to a folder they need special permissions for.

Comment: When I try your code it works: it shows the name of the group, not the SID. In your case, does the Security window show the name of that group or the SID?

Comment: @GabrielLuci It shows me the name of the group. Are you saying that when you ran my code it printed out all of the AD groups as well as the local groups?

Comment: Correct. When I tried it myself it showed all the group names, and filtering by a prefix (like a domain name) worked just fine.

Comment: I'm noticing now that your path is `W:\` - is that a remote path? Is the computer you are running this from joined to the same domain as the server? It's possible that your local computer has no trust with the domain the group is on, and therefore can't resolve the name automatically.

Comment: @GabrielLuci Oh my god, silly mistake from my part. The groups on my domain needed to be prefixed with "MY_DOMAIN_NAME\". I got that from your last response. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Groups that are on a domain need to be prefaced with the name of the domain followed by a backslash. So instead of:

```
$GroupPrefix = "A_Known_Prefix_Of_Each_Group"
```

I needed to do:

```
$GroupPrefix = "MY_DOMAIN_NAME\A_Known_Prefix_Of_Each_Group"
```